# ReactTable setState on columns is not changing layout

Tags: reactjs, react-table

first I should mention that I'm very new to react so this might be something silly..

I've struggled to get [ReactTable's](https://react-table.js.org/) column to be sortable with the help of [mattlockyer's gist](https://gist.github.com/mattlockyer/2ece67a544c4e062411328144dabc9da)

What I don't understand is I call setState on columns and then the render call is triggered correctly but it doesn't update the layout.

The render function "columns" contains an updated object with the correct column order, however render does not change the column order nor does sorting columns content.

This is the code in question,

```
this.setState({
  columns: newColLayout,
}, () => {
  this.mountEvents();
});
```

It will trigger a render, but the columns stay the same.

Ive put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/CynderR/pen/qMXVLg?editors=0011) with my current work and with comments about the code in question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i think i figured out whats going on.

The issue is splice modifies the state without triggering a change event, then when the event is fired from setStat, react doesn't see the change made to the column layout as it matches the current value.

The way i get around this is by cloning the column array using slice.

```
// Clone the current column state.
const columnClone = this.state.columns.slice(0);
// Remove item from array and stick it in a new position.
columnClone.splice(i, 0, columnClone.splice(this.draggedCol, 1)[0]);
```

[Here is the updated code](https://codepen.io/CynderR/pen/GXvxbp?editors=0011)...

Still might be improved by someone who has more experience with react.